# Function hover - mistake

Tags: jquery, hover

Welcome.

I want to get the effect that:
When you move the picture on it appears div.description. After leaving the image div disappears.

```
        <li>
            <section class="projekt">
                <img src="images/projects/projekt1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="description">

                </div>
            </section>
        </li>
```

I should add that the div is positioned absolutely descriprion the picture, and has enabled display: none;
Below code which unfortunately does not work like it should. When you move the image appears in the div but disappears after 1 second at a speed of 100ms instead remain.

```
   $('section.projekt img').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).next().fadeOut(100);
        }
    );
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the description div come over img that fired mouseout of img

```
  $('section.projekt img').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
            // add mouseout to description div not img
            $(this).next().mouseout(function(){$(this).fadeOut(100);})
        }
    );​
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with CSS:

```
.section:hover .description {
    ...
}
```

For "fade" effect, read more about [CSS animation](http://www.webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/).

Comment: But you won't have the fade effect. Also the question is about jQuery hover and not CSS hover:)